# Where can I suggest spell check improvements?

Tags: dictionary, spell-checking, contributing

I've been surprised by some of the words that applications in Ubuntu think deserve a red underline.

How can I contribute to Ubuntu to by improving the spell checking in its applications?

Comment: The checks are not performed by AskUbuntu but by the browser. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3385126/1626345).

Comment: Or by individual programs such as LibreOffice.

Comment: Found it. :D :D

Answer (score 8):

Both Chromium and IE do not not underline the word `curation` on my system. From the context menu I assume Chromium uses Google translate.

Firefox does underline it. Select the word and right click. You will see an option 'add to dictionary'.  After adding it the line is no longer marked. If they did their job well this word is not sent to their servers ;)

LibreOffice has its own dictionary. Highlight the word and press <kbd>f7</kbd>. You can then add it to your dictionary.

All of these are local and there is not a central database to report this.

---

After some more digging!

They all seem to use Hunspell. http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/

> Hunspell is the spell checker of LibreOffice, OpenOffice.org, Mozilla Firefox 3 & Thunderbird, Google Chrome, and it is also used by proprietary software packages, like Mac OS X, InDesign, memoQ, Opera and SDL Trados.

So the place to report them is here: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=143754&atid=756395

---

Chromium also uses [Hunspell](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/editing-the-spell-checking-dictionaries).

> You can also help by reviewing word lists of words we've identified as popular but not in the dictionary. Please contact brettw AT chromium.org if you are interested.

So this will/should work for all the software mentioned in this answer :)

Comment: What about the software you haven't mentioned?